# Finding critical points of the function $f(x,y)=xy^3-yx^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tried to use the second partial derivative test to find critical points of the function $f(x,y)=xy^3-yx^3$. However this test is not applicable, as I find $(0,0)$ as the only stationary point to the function and the value of $\Delta = f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2=0$.
Are there any other methods? Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a critical point to you?

Comment: I mean finding the local max/min of the function.

Comment: Since the function can be written as $ \ xy·(y^2 - x^2) \ \ , $ it is equal to zero on the lines $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ y \ =\ 0 \ \ , \ \ y \ = \ \pm x \ \ , $ so the critical point is "degenerate", which is why the Hessian provides no useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $(0,0)$ is the only critical point, and yes the second derivative test fails for this function. However, here it is very easy to recognize that the origin is a saddle point, because $f(t,t^2)=t^7-t^5$ changes sign at $t=0$ (from positive to negative).

Since we have found one curve, namely $\gamma(t)=(t,t^2)$, along which $f$ has arbitrary sign, it follows $f$ does not have a local max, nor a local min at the origin, hence it is a saddle.

Comment: Tks a lot. I got it

Answer (score -1):

The given function is:

$f(x, y) = x y \left( y^2 - x^2 \right)$.

Using first derivative test, we find that $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ is the unique critical point for $f$.

The Hessian test fails for this function $f$ as $Hf$ is a zero matrix when we substitute $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ in its entries.

Since $f$ takes both positive and negative values near the critical point $(0, 0)$, we conclude that the origin is a saddle point for the given function $f$.

(A MATLAB surface plot is shown for illustration.)

[[image: MATLAB surface plot of <span class=]$f(x, y)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y6jQ.jpg)

Comment: Tks a lot, I got it.

Comment: What have you done to produce that plot? It looks nothing like the actual graph!